# [macosx]does dlopen call open and read functions?

Tags: macos, intercept, function-interposition

I've intercepted(interposed) dlopen function under MacOS X and some other functions.
I see how my applications calls dlopen in the log, but don't find anything related to open/read functions after dynamic library was dlopened. How does the system accesses and reads the dynamic library file? I've looked at the source code of dyld, and it does call open/read on dlopen.
Can anybody let me know what I'm missing?
intercepted functions:
dlopen, open, read, write, access, all stat functions, close, etc.

thanks, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: How are you intercepting? strace?

Comment: no, using dyld interposing, through DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

After dlopen() succeeds then dlsym() would typically be called to look up functions etc in the library.

Comment: yeah, I understand that part.
The question is how the system reads out the library from the file system. I need to load application libraries from special storage container. I see the dlopen calls on my libraries, but no open/read functions

Comment: In that case you can probably just pull the Darwin source and look at that, no ? http://www.opensource.apple.com/